# Is it possible to change save path of a file saved by an external library?

Tags: python, file-io, output-directory

I use a library in python called `pyansys` in which I use a method called `save_as_vtk`.

There it is: [documentation](https://akaszynski.github.io/pyansys/loading_results.html?highlight=save_as_vtk#pyansys.rst.ResultFile.save_as_vtk)

This method generates a file for me and saves it to my working directory. I would like that file to be saved elsewhere... I don't want it moved because sometimes it is 20+ Gb and it would take too long.

Anybody has an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the `pyansys` package.

This was answered in https://github.com/akaszynski/pyansys/issues/219

Repeated here:

> It appears that ResultFile.save_as_vtk already has a filename parameter:

```
def save_as_vtk(self, filename, rsets=None, result_types=['ENS']):
    """Writes results to a vtk readable file.

    The file extension will select the type of writer to use.
    ``'.vtk'`` will use the legacy writer, while ``'.vtu'`` will
    select the VTK XML writer.

    Parameters
    ----------
    filename : str
        Filename of grid to be written.  The file extension will
        select the type of writer to use.  ``'.vtk'`` will use the
        legacy writer, while ``'.vtu'`` will select the VTK XML
        writer.
```